Prisma Downgrading or reverting updated migrations
I recently updated my Prisma.Schema with CUIDs and updated the migration. After some realizations and discussions I reverted my changes back.
Earlier State,
model User {
  id        Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime    @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  email     String      @unique
  name      String?
  Note      Note[]
}

i.e.
id        Int         @id @default(autoincrement())

changed to
id        String     @id @default(cuid())

Command used to update the migration,
prisma migrate dev --preview-feature

and now reverted back to original i.e. autoincrement manually in schema file.
Now to apply this revert, when I run npx prisma migrate dev to generate a migration, I get the following error,
Step 13 Changed the type of `userId` on the `Note` table. No cast exists, the column would be dropped and recreated, which cannot be done since the column is required and there is data in the table.

In my actual tables I havent really updated the integer values to string values. Even though the data type was earlier updated to a String, but those Strings are still technically integers saved as Strings.
Prisma suggests that I run this command,
npx prisma migrate dev --create-only

and manually update the file. I havent done this step before so I am not sure what to update in the migration file created. I dont want Prisma to drop all the tables containing the records I already have. Is there a way for me to not loose all my data? I know I can manually create a backup in postgresql but isnt there a better way? Whats the best possible way to fix this?

When you say you "updated the migration", what do you mean? Did you generate a migration? Or several? Did you run it (them)?

@PerttuHaliseva - I updated the question with relevant information on how to update and what command I used to revert back. Hope this helps clarify

I'm still not quite clear on what your actual question is; the question's title refers to reverting migrations, but I'm starting to feel like you're asking how to migrate a field from one data type to another without losing data. If this is the case, then look up a pattern called "expand and contract". Prisma has a good guide on how to utilize it to 1) add a new column (string ID), 2) update all the rows with the new ID, and 3) drop old ID column.
